# counting multiple sets of int values in a file

Tags: java, loops, controls, nested-loops

so i need to input a file with data like this

```
Joe Schmoe
76.5 20 30 25 10 75.9
Jilly Momilly Schmill
50.5 30 30 35 37 28 32 35 34 34 49.2
Gail Quail
62.3 15 17 10 3 10 63.6
Frank Crank
83.2 5 83.2
John Quann
57.9 30 32 35 32 30 57.2
```

i need the program to read the data and summarize it for each person
 example for Joe Schmoe out put would be

```
4   85  21.25   0.5999999999999943
```

which is the number of days (ints), total mins (sum of ints), average mins per day sum/days, and the final value is the first double minus the second.

my algorithm for reading the data is:

```
public void summaryData()
    {
        try 
        {
            while (inputStream.hasNext())
            {
                line = inputStream.nextLine();
                firstWeight = inputStream.nextDouble();
                while (inputStream.hasNextInt()) 
                {   
                            sum += inputStream.nextInt();
                    count ++;
                    avg = (sum/count);  
                }
                lastWeight = inputStream.nextDouble();
                        outputStream.println(count + "    " + sum + "    " + avg +  "    " + (lastWeight-firstWeight));
            if(inputStream.hasNext())
                    inputStream.nextLine(); 
            }
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) 
        {
            System.out.print(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

my problem is this i need the int count and the sum for each individual to start over rather than adding them all together.

any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated

sample output:

```
4    85    21.0    -0.5999999999999943
13    380    29.0    -1.2999999999999972
18    435    24.0    1.3000000000000043
19    440    23.0    0.0
24    599    24.0    -0.6999999999999957
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your count at each new line

```
...
while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
  count = 0;
...
```

It looks like you also have your math reversed for the first and last...

```
lastWeight-firstWeight
```

should  probably be

```
firstWeight-lastWeight
```

Comment: my output is now 4    85    21.0    -0.5999999999999943
9    380    42.0    -1.2999999999999972
5    435    87.0    1.3000000000000043
1    440    440.0    0.0
5    599    119.0    -0.6999999999999957

Comment: it is lastWeight minus firstWeight were checking to see if the participant lost weight thanks for the help do i also reset the sum for each individual?

Comment: The same pattern should do the trick... add "sum = 0;" on the line after count = 0;